# How to print JSON array inside script tag?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to display JSON array inside `<script>` tag, is that possible?

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

```
<script>
    var x =  JSON.stringify(data);

var json = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "empdata.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();
 </script>
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

```
<script>

var videos = {"employee_id":"1","employee_name":"Steve","designation":"VP","hired_date":"2013-08-01","salary"
:"6000"};

</script>
```

Comment: perhaps with ` <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>`;  <- don't miss the java-script semi-colon though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea you just echo it like this, assuming you have an $array of parameters like `array("employee_id"=>1 ... )`

```
var videos = <?php echo json_encode(array(
    "employee_id"=>1
)); ?>;  // <- don't miss the java-script semi-colon though
```

This should just print

```
  var videos = {"employee_id":1};
```

PHP doesn't care where you echo it at, in your page, it doesn't have a concept about what a `<script>` tag is.  All it knows is some things are php code, everything else is string content.

OR you could just do this

```
  var videos = <?php echo '{"employee_id":1}'; ?>;
```

But that is kind of pointless, unless you mean like this.

```
  var videos = <?php echo '{"employee_id":'.$employee_id.'}'; ?>;
```

Or you can do this way to

```
   var videos = {"employee_id":1};
```

And just put it in there, I don't understand anymore?

If you mean from a file containing your json, then sure.

```
<?php
 $json = file_get_contents( 'pathtofile.json');
?>

<script> ... etc.\

 var videos = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

PHP can read files, and it can echo the contents of those files, PHP doesn't care whats in them.  The only catch is the content has to be valid Json for the javascript to work.  But php doesn't care if it's JSON, XML, Binary etc. it's all text because PHP is a loosely typed language.  In fact php doesn't care if your Javascript works, it has no concept of what javascript is.

In fact this works too ( assuming image.jpg is a real image file. ).

```
  $jpg = file_get_contents( 'image.jpg' );
  echo '<img src="'. $jpg.'" \>
```

OR

```
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   echo file_get_contents( 'image.jpg' );  //assuming there is no other content
```

Comment: is not working results: `var videos =  <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span>.......`

Comment: @PerfectGohan - That looks like the beginning of an error message.  Unfortunately, you only shared the presentational elements, and omitted the actual error message.

Comment: @gilly3 - I imagine that is the root of the problem anyway.

Comment: @PerfectGohan - you have an array of information to feed json_encode, rihgt?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix is it possible to echo straight away from `'url': "empdata.json"` file or any json url ?

Comment: @PerfectGohan - I don't understand, can you echo 'url': "empdata.json" ? only if you do you quotes right or use a newdoc or herdoc style.  I see a lot of javascript in your question and no PHP.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix sorry because I'm confused what I mean: if possible to echo json array directly from json file

Comment: You mean you have json in a file>?  sure.

Comment: yes I have this empdata.json file that contains this array `[[],{"employee_id":"1","employee_name":"Steve","designation":"VP","hired_date":"2013-08-01","salary"
:"6000"}]` is it possible to get the array from the file and echo inside < script > tag

Comment: It's not an array if it's in a file, it's just text.  So the question is can php read text from a file, sure it can.  Can it then echo that text, you bet ya.  See my update.  Remember it's just text to php, even an image file is just text to php, maybe it's binary data but php don't really care about that unless you tell it to.  That is the beauty of php, its loosely typed.

Comment: I hope that helps, remember it's just text. Really, there is no magic in the hat.  Frosty is just snow.

Comment: Sure, remember it's just plain old text to php.